# setting empty value inside select if is empty select AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

can someone tell me how can I make empty value, that if nothing is in list of select, show "n/a"

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/wPrKrr?editors=1010

**template**

```
    <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="select">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedBoard" ng-change="changeBoard(selectedBoard)">
     <option ng-repeat="item in boards" value="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</option>   
 </select>

 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedList">
   <option ng-repeat="item in downloadedLists" value="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</option> 
 </select>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<option ng-repeat=" item in downloadsLists" >{{$index || "n/a"}}</option>
```

Comment: Some explanation could come quite helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedList">
  <option disabled selected value
         ng-show="downloadedLists.length == 0">n/a</option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in downloadedLists" value="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</option> 
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <option value="">N/A </option>  
 <option ng-repeat="item in boards" value="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</option>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer code only answer doesn't tend to help much.